# Login con Angular en Google Chrome solicita certificado para autenticar tu identidad

Tags: angular, login, google-chrome, certificado-ssl

Tengo una aplicación web desarrollada con Angular 7 en el front y con Java en el back, está desplegada y funcionando bajo https.

Situación: cuando el usuario tiene certificados instalados en el navegador (chrome en este caso), al momento de hacer Login, se despliega un pop up informando de que puede utilizar este certificado para autenticarse.

Es este pop up en concreto:

[image]

Problema: quiero evitar que se solicite este certificado ya que la única manera de autenticarse es a través del formulario (usuario, contraseña).

Alternativas: He leído que a través del navegador se puede configurar la gestión de certificados, sin embargo me gustaría poder controlarlo desde la propia aplicación para que el usuario no tenga que hacer nada.
Las peticiones se realizan a través del HttpClient de angular. He revisado la documentación de Angular al respecto pero no he encontrado nada. ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Toda ayuda es bien recibida.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Con respecto a los certificados no hay nada que puedas hacer desde la aplicación Angular ya que el bloque lo realiza el navegador antes de cargar los recursos del sitio web, esa parte queda a criterio del cliente que accede a la web si quiere instalar un certificado que es auto generado y no proviene de una entidad certificadora acreditada, de lo contrario cualquier persona podría redireccionarte a una web falsa y decir que es la original instalándote el certificado.

Comment: Como tienes un certificado SSL sobre piperlab.es verifica si tu certificado SSL te permite subdominios y así puede utilizar el mismo certificado, sino debes o extender la cobertura de tu certificado SSL para poder aplicar a subdominios o utiliza un certificado oficial gratuito como los de https://letsencrypt.org/ para generar un SSL valido para el subdominio, el único inconveniente(o ventaja de seguridad según lo mires) es que debes estar actualizando el certificado SSL cada 3 meses que es el periodo de validez (aunque hay programas que ayudan a automatizar esta parte).

Comment: En cierto modo creo que debería de existir la opción de quitarlo o no solicitarlo, ya que al acceder al login de otras aplicaciones no me salta el pop up y este es el comportamiento que me gustaría conseguir.

Comment: Es importante diferenciar entre los certificados ssl de la propia aplicación, y los instalados en chrome. En este caso ya existe un certificado letsencrypt para servir la app bajo https; el certificado del pop up es un certificado de prueba autofirmado, generado localmente para replicar esta incidencia.